# jqGrid inline edit using successfunc

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that allows inline editing. Here is my onselect that handles it:

```
onSelectRow: function(id)
        {

            $('tr[id="'+id+'"]').change(function () {

                saveparameters = {
                    "successfunc" : function(response) {

                        alert(response)

                    },
                    "url" : null,
                    "extraparam" : {},
                    "aftersavefunc" : null,
                    "errorfunc": null,
                    "afterrestorefunc" : null,
                    "restoreAfterError" : true,
                    "mtype" : "POST"
                }

                $('#breakdownGrid').jqGrid('saveRow', id, saveparameters);

            });

            if(id && id!==lastsel)
            {

                editparameters = {
                    "keys" : false,
                    "oneditfunc" : null,
                    "successfunc" : null,
                    "url" : null,
                    "extraparam" : {},
                    "aftersavefunc" : null,
                    "errorfunc": null,
                    "afterrestorefunc" : null,
                    "restoreAfterError" : true,
                    "mtype" : "POST"

                }

                $('#breakdownGrid').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                $('#breakdownGrid').jqGrid('editRow',id, editparameters); lastsel=id;
            }
        }

    });
```

You can see that I have a change event on the tr that fires off and runs saveRow. This works fine without using the successfunc or if I just return true in the successfunc. I am trying to figure out how I can use the response from the server in the successfunc. I need to do an additional check on my editurl page. I am not sure what I need to send back from that page. I can do all the work on that page and send back a true or false but it's not working. I have the alert in there right now and it just displays [object object].

I have also tried sending back JSON and parsing it but I cannot get it to work.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try 
alert(response.responseText);